# Flagged, but the answer was edited

Tags: discussion, review, flagging

If I flag a question/answer but it gets edited before the reviewers review my flagging, what happens?

Is this even possible?

Comment: Edits can dequeue a post (and thus clear/decline the flag). [Off hand I am not sure about all the details.] This is especially true for LQ flags, which you likely have in mind.

Comment: I've had flags declined by a moderator due to an edit occurring between the flag and the review, so the flag may persist. Depending on the moderator or the question, may be either marked helpful if the edit doesn't achieve anything or declined if it fixed the issue.

Comment: @Nij could you be precise on what happened. How do you know it was a moderator that declined it?  (Also what type of flag?)

Comment: @quid - a flag for NAA, on a different SE, the note gives *declined - the edit appears to answer the question*. I assumed this went through moderator but having just checked, it may well have been automatic.

Comment: @Nij thanks for the details. Actually, given that the reason is given I'd also assume it went through moderators. But, really I'd not know for sure.